# Yet another "Spring ,could not resolve place holder"

Tags: java, spring

I am pulling my hair out.  Rather than post my actual problem, I am posting a simpler version because I cannot even get that simpler version to work.  My actual program uses the same exact techniques... meaning I look for the properties in the classpath, etc.

I am using `Spring 4.2.1`. I've searched stackoverflow, and many online examples... but nothing seems to work.  I believe the program is finding the properties file because I am not getting the `IOException` for `FileNotFoundException`.

Any ideas?  I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.  This is my first exposure to Spring.

Here is my `Beans.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurator"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <description>
            Configurer that replaces ${...} placeholders with values
            from a properties file
        </description>

        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:user.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="user" class="com.my.User">
        <description>
            Load Properties of the user bean from user.properties
            file
        </description>
        <property name="email" value="${user.email}" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is my `user.properties` file

```
user.email=user@yoyo.com
```

The main app to create a user and print out the user's email

```
package com.my;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

        User usr = (User) context.getBean("user");

        System.out.println("Email = " + usr.getEmail());

    }
}
```

And a simple `User` class:

```
package com.my;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
    private String email;
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public User() {
    }

}
```

Finally, the stack trace:

```
Sep 29, 2015 8:07:23 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@3fa77460: startup date [Tue Sep 29 08:07:23 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 29, 2015 8:07:23 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
Sep 29, 2015 8:07:23 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'user' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'user.email' in string value "${user.email}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'user.email' in string value "${user.email}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:673)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:519)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.my.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'user.email' in string value "${user.email}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:208)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Where is `user.properties` located in your project?

Comment: in the 'src" folder in eclipse... so it is at the the same level as the com.my package.

Comment: Have you tried changing your `user.properties` file name to spring's default name `application.properties`? It looks like spring is not fiding your properties file.

Comment: Could it be you have a maven project?

Comment: Can you try enabling debug-level logging on the org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport class? The loadProperties method in that class logs out the properties files that it processes, as well as when it cannot find one of the files in your list of locations.

Comment: Late breaking news... so sorry about that.  I am using eclipse with a standard Java Project.  Not Maven, etc.  The errors I posted were from eclipse.  So I created a runnable JAR in eclipse (File | Export | Runnable Jar) and naturally, all the spring jars are included in my MainApp.jar.  When I invoke     **java -jar MainApp.jar**  from the command line, the program works.  Does that information help?  Seems odd to me... I would expect the IDE environment to be well behaved.

Comment: Thanks for at trying to help.  Runnable jar works (as expected) from the command line.  As does creating the MainApp.jar (non-runnable, so it has no libs embeddd in it) and invoking from the command line as long as the classpaths are set correctly, etc.  So... I am thinking this is not a super pressing issue since there has to be a setting in eclipse that is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar problem and what research I've done suggests using:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:user.properties" local-override="true" ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
```

instead of your

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurator"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <description>
            Configurer that replaces ${...} placeholders with values
            from a properties file
        </description>

        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:user.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```